# Android Lollipop Trusted Face Missing

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

So, I've been having this problem; I want to use Trusted face on my HTC One (M8) stock **Android 5.1**, but in Smart Lock, only these options come up:

- Trusted devices

  - None
- Trusted places

  - None
- Trusted voice

  - On
- On-body detection

  - Off

The option for Trusted face, isn't there, not even grayed out. In my Trust agents, Smart Lock (Google) *is* activated.

The only things I have done to the phone is root it, install TWRP recovery, and changed the DPI from 480 to 430. I don't think any of these are causing the issue, as I tested the default 480 DPI, and it was working fine on **Lollipop 5.0.1**.

Anyone know how to fix this? I'm going to perform a backup via TWRP, then factory reset to see if the feature is back, I'll keep you all updated.

Comment: You might have luck flashing [the appropriate gapps](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/themes-apps/gapps-smart-unlock-android-5-0-t2962765)

Comment: @Huey Thank you sir, after switching back to Lollipop from Marshmallow (still didn't have Trusted Face) and flashing that file, it finally showed up! If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as such.